# QUrl parsing fails

Tags: c++, qt, qurl

I have a QUrl as this: `https://www.example.com/success.html#token=XYZ&user=guest` and I want to obtain the value of the token i.e. `XYZ`

My current code

```
QString token = url.queryItemValue(QString("token"));
cout << QString("access token is %1").arg(access_token);
```

returns an empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it returns an empty string. `token` is not a valid query item in your given URL. For `https://www.example.com/success.html?token=XYZ&user=guest` it would be valid. Usually `#` is used for an anchor name reference and not for parameters. If you really have URLs like that, you need to either first convert the `#` into a `?` or custom parse the URL. You can get the stuff followed by the `#` with `QUrl::fragment()`.

Comment: Oh. Didn't spot the `#` there.